# Opening up part of a secured application without compromising the entire application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There's a subset of users which will not have access to the system I'm implementing in the beginning but I need a mechanism for them to capture data for one specific part of the process.

An authorized user creates the original record for a Person with some basic details i.e. First name, last name etc.

I then create a 'DataRequest' record which has a unique guid and the external user is sent an email with a path which is effectively `http://sampleapplication/Person/Complete?guid=xxxx`

The external user adds additional details like Date of Birth, Eye colour etc, submits and saves to the DB. The DataRequest for that guid is then expired and cannot be accessed again.

The Complete action doesn't have any authorization as these external users do not have user accounts.

My preference is to force these users to use the system but at this stage I'm not sure it's practical.

Is this a bad practice?
Should I be implementing some additional security on this like a one time password / passcode contained in the email? Are there alternative approaches I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with opening up a section of your site to the public. Tons of websites have secured and unsecured sections. However, there's also nothing saying that you have to expose your secure site at all. You can create another site that merely has access to that change those records and make that site alone, public.

As far as securing the information of the user, passcodes by email are the invention of some developer somewhere with limited mental ability or a severe lack of sleep. If the link is only available by email (not discoverable by search engines and not easily guessable), then anyone with the link will also have the passcode, making the passcode to access the link redundant.

You should however log when the email is used to finish the record and then disallow further uses.

Comment: I like the idea of isolating it as a separate application.

I also doubted the value of the passcode in the email given that the link is unique and only available in that email. My only concern with the fact the link is only known to the person receiving the email is I'm sort of relying on security by obscurity. I guess I'll need to put some mechanisms in place to ensure the guid cannot be spoofed by an attacker. The Data Request records are being expired once they've been used once.